# Theres an error for an identifier in the for loop statement

Tags: python

```
import json as js  

def find_dist(latlng_1, latlng_2):
    '''
    This function calculate distanse in km between two point on Earth
    whose coordinates are passed as two lists and returns rounded distanse
    '''
    lat1, lon1 = latlng_1[0] * pi / 180, latlng_1[1] * pi / 180
    lat2, lon2 = latlng_2[0] * pi / 180, latlng_2[1] * pi / 180
    d = 2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2) ** 2))
    return round(d, 2)

file = "countriesV2.json"  
limit = 28875    
f = open(file)
contries = json.load(f)
first_20 = {}

for ​contry in contries:
    if contry['population'] >= limit:
        first_20[contry['alpha3Code']] = contry['latlng']
        if len(first_20) == 20:
            break

total_dist = 0
keys = list(first_20.keys())
for ​i in range(len(keys) - 1):
    for j in range(len(keys[i + 1:])):
        total_dist += find_dist(first_20[keys[i]], first_20[keys[j]])
total_dist = round(total_dist, 2)

print(total_dist)
```

Even if the syntax for the for loop is correct the same error keep showing up.
The following is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-25-4f6d923a5198>", line 27
for ​contry in contries:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: You have an invisible unicode character (zero width space) in that line. Delete it and retype it.

Comment: In place of `for ​i in range(len(keys) - 1):` you should consider using `for i, key_i in enumerate(keys[:-1]):`. This will let you replace `keys[i]` with `key_i` inside the loop. The inner loop might be `for j, key_j in enumerate(keys[i + 1:]):`.